# How to find the number of text objects in BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping a wikipedia page using BeautifulSoup in python and I was wondering whether there is anyone to know the number of text objects in an HTML object.  For example the following code gets me the following HTML:

```
soup.find_all(class_ = 'toctext')

<span class="toctext">Actors and actresses</span>, <span class="toctext">Archaeologists and anthropologists</span>, <span class="toctext">Architects</span>, <span class="toctext">Artists</span>, <span class="toctext">Broadcasters</span>, <span class="toctext">Businessmen</span>, <span class="toctext">Chefs</span>, <span class="toctext">Clergy</span>, <span class="toctext">Criminals</span>, <span class="toctext">Conspirators</span>, <span class="toctext">Economists</span>, <span class="toctext">Engineers</span>, <span class="toctext">Explorers</span>, <span class="toctext">Filmmakers</span>, <span class="toctext">Historians</span>, <span class="toctext">Humourists</span>, <span class="toctext">Inventors / engineers</span>, <span class="toctext">Journalists / newsreaders</span>, <span class="toctext">Military: soldiers/sailors/airmen</span>, <span class="toctext">Monarchs</span>, <span class="toctext">Musicians</span>, <span class="toctext">Philosophers</span>, <span class="toctext">Photographers</span>, <span class="toctext">Politicians</span>, <span class="toctext">Scientists</span>, <span class="toctext">Sportsmen and sportswomen</span>, <span class="toctext">Writers</span>, <span class="toctext">Other notables</span>, <span class="toctext">English expatriates</span>, <span class="toctext">References</span>, <span class="toctext">See also</span>
```

I can get the first text object by running the following:

```
soup.find_all(class_ = 'toctext')[0].text
```

My goal here is to get and store all of the text objects in a list.  I'm doing this by using a for loop, however I don't know how many text objects there are in the html block.  Naturally I would hit an error if I get to an index that doesn't exist  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for...in` loop.

```
In [13]: [t.text for t in soup.find_all(class_ = 'toctext')]
Out[13]: 
['Actors and actresses',
 'Archaeologists and anthropologists',
 'Architects',
 'Artists',
 'Broadcasters',
 'Businessmen',
 'Chefs',
 'Clergy',
 'Criminals',
 'Conspirators',
 'Economists',
 'Engineers',
 'Explorers',
 'Filmmakers',
 'Historians',
 'Humourists',
 'Inventors / engineers',
 'Journalists / newsreaders',
 'Military: soldiers/sailors/airmen',
 'Monarchs',
 'Musicians',
 'Philosophers',
 'Photographers',
 'Politicians',
 'Scientists',
 'Sportsmen and sportswomen',
 'Writers',
 'Other notables',
 'English expatriates',
 'References',
 'See also']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
for txt in soup.find_all(class_ = 'toctext'):
    print(txt.text)
```